# Interrupting a Program with a Button

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, rpi.gpio

Currently tying to stop the middle of a command if the user presses a certain button.  I tried this bit of code below and it doesn't seem to work.  I know that you can use `control-C` to have a KeyboardInterrupt, but I would like it so that I could use a button.

```python
import os
def put(command):
    os.system(command)

elif (RPIO.input(25) == GPIO.LOW):#button 3
        if direct == "":
            time.sleep(.5)
            while True:
                put("sudo ffmpeg -i \"" + q3 + "\" -f s16le -ar 22.05k -ac 1 - | sudo ./pifm - " + str(freq)) 
                rebootpro() #reboot the program
                if RPIO.input(25) == GPIO.LOW: #if the button is pushed, stop the program.
                    rebootpro()
        else:
            put("sudo ffmpeg -i \"" + q3 + "/" + direct + "\" -f s16le -ar 22.05k -ac 1 - | sudo ./pifm - " + str(freq))
            rebootpro()
```

I am trying to stop the program while a `os.system` command is running, is there any way to do this? (python 2.7)

Thanks,
Cody

Comment: Do you need to stop the `os.system` command too, or just break out of the python?  You may need to look into other methods to launch whatever is in `os.system()` if you just need to break the python code.  To break both, i think you will be looking at multiple scripts and "watchdogs" to look for the input separate from the main script.

Comment: Just a tip, don't use `os.system()`, use `subprocess.call()`. `os.system` calls your command through the shell, which isn't necessary and can be a security risk. `subprocess.call` just creates a new process. Read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#security) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) for more explanation.

Comment: Have a look at `subprocess.Popen`. This will open the program in the background, instead of waiting for the program to finish. That way you can still run python code. Use `Popen.poll()` to see in the program is still running. Use `Popen.kill()` to terminate the program. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I will looking into subprocess sense that is what most of you suggest.  I will also be removing the os.system command, again thank for the help!

Comment: @Gerben Thanks for the help so much!  Could you give an example of how to use the subprocess.Popen and kill it when you want?  You'll have to excuse me as I am a beginner, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
import shlex, subprocess

while True:
  command_line = "sudo ffmpeg -i \"" + q3 + "\" -f s16le -ar 22.05k -ac 1 - | sudo ./pifm - " + str(freq)
  args = shlex.split(command_line)
  p = subprocess.Popen(args)
  while p.poll() is None and RPIO.input(25)==GPIO.HIGH :
    time.sleep(.5)

  if RPIO.input(25) == GPIO.LOW :
    break
  //else rerun command again
```

Comment: I know this is like a month old, but I thought I would let you know how this went. I get an error when I run this EXACT command.

  File "./sub2.py", line 8, in <module>
    args = shlex.split(command_line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 279, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 269, in next
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 172, in read_token
    raise ValueError, "No closing quotation"
ValueError: No closing quotation